# How do I identify a rogue program using mac text to speech

Tags: macos, text-to-speech

Every other week my mac randomly starts speaking to me in the default computer voice saying something along the lines of "Password or username incorrect."  Unfortunately, I'm usually caught off guard or have audio playing when the message begins. Therefore I don't know exactly what is said.

Considering hackers don't usually announce their failed password cracking efforts, I believe this is most likely a practical joke being played on me.  Nevertheless, it's a little alarming.

I need help forming a strategy to identify the rogue program using text to speech.

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://apple.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0):

You could rename `/usr/bin/say` as `/usr/bin/say.original` so it doesn't talk any more.

Then write a new script called `/usr/bin/say` which runs a `ps` command to write its own and its parent's process id into a text file for you to inspect to see who/what called it.

Failing that, you could check your `crontab` and that of the root user with:

```
crontab -l
```

and

```
sudo crontab -l
```

and see if there is anything suspicious in there, like a script called `pesterMathew`.